# Actor not moving in screen2d

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

I want to use moveToAction and move the actor. But its not moving if i use moveToAction. If change x,y in draw method it works, but not with movetoaction

```
public class Aks extends Actor {
    private State state;
    private MainGame game;

    private TextureAtlas movingAtlas;
    private Animation movingAnimation;

    private float elapsedTime = 0f;

    public Aks(MainGame game) {
        this.game = game;

        movingAtlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("atlas/myaltas/atlas.atlas"));
        movingAnimation = new Animation(1f/15f, movingAtlas.getRegions());

        TextureRegion texture = (TextureRegion) movingAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true);
        setBounds(getX(),getY(),texture.getRegionWidth(),texture.getRegionHeight());

        MoveToAction moveAction = new MoveToAction();
        moveAction.setPosition(300f, 300f);
        moveAction.setDuration(10f);
        this.addAction(moveAction);


        addListener(new ActorGestureListener(){
            @Override
            public void tap(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int count, int button) {
                Gdx.app.log("Tag", "Actor touched x = " );
                super.tap(event, x, y, count, button);

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Batch batch, float alpha){
        drawFlying(batch);
    }

    void drawFlying(Batch batch){
        TextureRegion texture = (TextureRegion) movingAnimation.getKeyFrame(elapsedTime, true);
        setBounds(getX(),getY(),texture.getRegionWidth(),texture.getRegionHeight());
        Gdx.app.log("Tag", "x =" + getX() + " y =" + getY() );
        batch.draw(texture, getX(),getY(),50,50);
    }

    @Override
    public void act(float delta){
        elapsedTime = elapsedTime+delta;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needs to call super.act(delta), in the actor class, the act method control all the actions so if you don't call it, the actions wont happen, on the contrary you don't need to call super.draw() that's because actor class was created just for logical part of a entity, you must define what it will draw in case you need it.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your draw function needs to call super.draw(batch, alpha) for it to affect child actions.